# How do I snap a vertex along a local axis?

Tags: modeling, mesh, snapping

If I'm trying to move a vertex along any axis other than global X Y or Z, it doesn't snap to another line or face (at least not in a useful way). For example, this is what I want:

[image]

But trying to snap to a vertex results in this:

[image]

And snapping to an edge results in this:
[image]

The problem is that when I'm moving a vertex along a local axis, the snapping also uses the local axis. I'd like to move it along a local axis but use a global axis for the snapping.

EDIT: To explain my use case a bit; I do a lot of modeling for mechanical parts, and this situation comes up frequently. I have found 2 ways to accomplish this, but they are both fairly cumbersome.

One is to use a shrinkwrap modifier, but that requires creating a vertex group, setting up the modifier, and in some cases creating a new object to use for the target since the the object I'm wanting to snap to doesn't necessarily lie on the path I'm moving the vertex.

The other is to extrude the vertex beyond the point I want to snap it to and then use a boolean operation to clip the mesh. This one is a fairly bad solution though since a boolean operation requires the mesh to be manifold, and it often does unpredictable things.

The shrinkwrap method is the least painful method I've found, but I'd really like a way to do this simply and quickly, just like snapping a vertex in any other scenario.

Comment: - Consider a shrink wrap with a vertex group of one vertex

Comment: Static placement for single image  .. or dynamic placement for video.  If you explain your intended use a little more it would be helpful.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger I updated the question with a bit more about my use case. I'm not sure what you mean about static placement and dynamic placement though. Could you please explain that a bit?

Comment: To get result from the 1-st photo I switched Transform Orientation to Normal, set snapping to Edge and grabbed vertice down (normal X in my case). I used 2 planes, top one rotated by 45 degrees in Object mode. Is that what you want ?

Comment: @MrZak That doesn't seem to work for me. It still snaps to any arbitrary point along the edge, which is what's happening in the third photo. Is there something I'm missing? Does this not happen for you?

Comment: @MrZak It looks like he wants to translate the vertex along the local Z axis of its object, which your method doesn't do, does it?

Comment: @catlover2 of course it doesn't. I didn't know at the moment it's needed to snap to edge or vertex in the bottom precisely *and* grab along the local coordinates (to preserve original volume). At the moment I can think of using Edge snapping and grab along Y like [this](http://i.imgur.com/tkJJLui.jpg), so to hover mouse over vertice (it seems to me another way exhists, I just can't think now)

Comment: @mike I posted an idea, you edited your post, and my post was changed to a comment by someone else even though we started to have a dialogue at that post.  My original post is still part of my final idea.  I do not really understand your question enough to propose a new idea. I do not understand what is the the snapping your desire.  Can you explain in a different way the type of snapping you desire?  I would also use more color for contrast in your images.  Lastly your ideas in your edit seem to be the same as mine.  I disagree in the assessment of whether or not the work is excessive.

Answer (score 2):

Look at TinyCAD, aside the for me only downside that the edges need to be in the same mesh, it should be the perfect solution for you. It comes with Blender and can be activated in the preferences.

In your case i then would:

1. Create a duplicate of the edge from the lower object with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
2. Leave it in place by pressing <kbd>RMB</kbd>
3. Separate by selection with <kbd>P</kbd> press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept the first choice.
4. Go in Object Mode and select the new object and the upper object
5. Join those objects with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>
6. Now you select the joined object, go in Edit Mode and use the "V2X - Vertex at intersection" function of TinyCAD in the <kbd>RMB</kbd> menu.
7. You get a new vertex at the intersection, which you can then use to merge the corner of the upper object on.

As i mentioned, the add-on has the drawback that it needs you to join meshes, so i forked the add-on and adjusted the V2X function, if you have more of those situations it might be interesting for you to check it out.
My forked version got merged, so here the link to the original repository.
[TinyCAD/b28branch](https://github.com/zeffii/mesh_tiny_cad/tree/tinycad_b28)

Here a little explanatory visual:

[image]

This version is for Blender 2.8+
You **can** replace the files in the "scripts\addons\mesh_tiny_cad" folder of your Blender installation. I recommend to make a backup of the files first.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to your problem may be to use a different tool than snapping. If I were starting with your second image, and wanted to get to the first one, I would select the vertex you have selected in the second image, and use a vertex slide (<kbd>SHFT</kbd> - <kbd>V</kbd>). If the vertex was not exactly in the correct place after the slide, I'd use the move (<kbd>G</kbd>) tool, perhaps constrained to an axis if that was necessary, to adjust it.